# Functional programming: AggregateUntil function

Tags: c#, functional-programming

so here's an interesting problem.  i'm trying to use a functional approach to solve something that would be really easy in an imperative manner.  the goal is to take a sequence and foldl/reduce it to to a single value, however I want to stop and exit early once the accumulated value satisfies a given condition.  you might say I want to define `IEnumerable<T>.AggregateUntil`.  here's how I would write it in an imperative fashion:

```
public static TAccumulate AggregateUntil<TSource, TAccumulate>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    TAccumulate seed,
    Func<TSource, TAccumulate, TAccumulate> accumulate,
    Func<TAccumulate, bool> until)
{
    var result = seed;

    foreach (var s in source)
    {
        result = accumulate(s, result);

        if (until(result))
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

how would you go about writing that in a functional way, without the `foreach` loop?  i'm specifically trying to find a way of doing it in a way that doesn't cause me to have to re-implement `Aggregate` in its entirety, with just this one little behavior difference.  i also would like to do so without iterating over the collection twice.  I'm still working on this and will post an update if I figure it out, but if someone out there wants to help with the challenge that's welcome as well.

EDIT #1:

here's a stab at how to implement it without the `Until` concept, just to get the juices flowing:

```
private static TAccumulate AggregateUntil<TSource, TAccumulate>(
    IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    TAccumulate seed,
    Func<TSource, TAccumulate, TAccumulate> accumulate)
{
    using (var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        return AggregateUntil(enumerator, seed, accumulate);
    }
}

private static TAccumulate AggregateUntil<TSource, TAccumulate>(
    IEnumerator<TSource> source,
    TAccumulate seed,
    Func<TSource, TAccumulate, TAccumulate> accumulate)
{
    return source.MoveNext()
        ? AggregateUntil(source, accumulate(source.Current, seed), accumulate, until)
        : seed;
}
```

EDIT #2:

OK, I've implemented my goal function as far as functionality goes, but I haven't yet figured how to do it without just reimplementing basically all of the foldl/reduce/aggregate logic + the until condition.  I feel like I'm missing a basic trick of FP composability if I can't figure out how to re-use the logic in `Aggregate` as-is:

```
private static TAccumulate AggregateUntil<TSource, TAccumulate>(
    IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    TAccumulate seed,
    Func<TSource, TAccumulate, TAccumulate> accumulate,
    Func<TAccumulate, bool> until)
{
    using (var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        return AggregateUntil(enumerator, seed, accumulate, until);
    }
}

private static TAccumulate AggregateUntil<TSource, TAccumulate>(
    IEnumerator<TSource> source,
    TAccumulate seed,
    Func<TSource, TAccumulate, TAccumulate> accumulate,
    Func<TAccumulate, bool> until)
{
    TAccumulate result;

    return source.MoveNext()
        ? until(result = accumulate(source.Current, seed))
            ? result
            : AggregateUntil(source, result, accumulate, until)
        : seed;
}
```

Comment: Nothing c# specific but general advice Ive got when trying to exit fold/accumulate based on some condition is to use recucrsion.

Answer (score 1):

It really is best to use the imperative techniques, because the functional way of doing it is to use recursion and you can easily blow up the stack using recursion in C#, it's also much less efficient - there's an overhead to the recursive calls and you need to get the first item from the enumerable several times.

However, if you want to know how, this is it (as an extension method to IEnumerable):

```
    public static TAccumulate AggregateUntil<TSource, TAccumulate>(
        this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
        TAccumulate seed,
        Func<TSource, bool> predicate,
        Func<TSource, TAccumulate, TAccumulate> accumulate)
    {
        return source.Any()
            ? predicate(source.First())
                ? source.Skip(1).AggregateUntil(accumulate(source.First(), seed), predicate, accumulate)
                : seed
            : seed;
    }
```

If you use a functional first language like F# that has the pattern matching constructs for decomposing the head and tail of a list, and can do tail recursion, then the implementation is much simpler:

```
let rec foldUntil state folder pred = function
    | []      -> state
    | x :: xs -> if pred x
                 then foldUntil (folder state x) folder pred xs
                 else state
```

If you were to use my [Language-Ext](https://github.com/louthy/language-ext) library, then you could get close to this style with C#:

```
S FoldUntil<S,T>(IEnumerable<T> list, S state, Func<S, T, S> folder, Func<T, bool> pred) =>
    match(list,
        ()      => state,
        (x, xs) => pred(x)
                      ? FoldUntil(xs, folder(state, x), folder, pred)
                      : state);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
public static TAccumulate AggregateUntil<TSource, TAccumulate>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    TAccumulate seed,
    Func<TSource, TAccumulate, TAccumulate> accumulate,
    Func<TAccumulate, bool> until)
{
    return source.Select(s => seed = accumulate(s, seed))
                 .SkipWhile(s => !until(s))
                 .First();
}
```

The select isn't too nice, since we're keeping state. But I don't think it's possible to do without re-writing `Aggregate` to break on a condition or aggregating the list multiple times.

Comment: Shouldn't this fail in case if `until` returns `false` for all `s`?

Comment: @soon Yes, you're right - good catch. Will update when I get a chance